# Implementing a .h file into a main() in C programming

Tags: c, stack

I am new at C programming and I am trying to use the implementation of .h that I created in a main(). So far I have a .h file, a .c file that implements the .h file, and I am working on another .c file which has the main function. I have run the .h and .c implementation file and it works fine. I believe the part I am messing up on is using the implementation in the main file. The error I am getting is segmentation fault core dumped. This is what I am trying to do so far

```
//.h file
typedef struct stack{
    int* data;
    int size;
    int capacity;
} STACK;

STACK* MakeStack(int initialCapacity);
//Other Push,Pop,Grow Functions
```

My second file(prog1_2.c) is the implementation of this header file which performs the actions like it suppose to, for instance my MakeStack method is:

```
//prog1_2.c
STACK* MakeStack(int initialCapacity){
    struct stack *newStack = (struct stack*) malloc( sizeof(struct stack));
    newStack->size = 0;
    newStack->capacity = initialCapacity;
    newStack->data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*initialCapacity);
    return newStack;
}
```

Lastly, the part that I am having trouble with is this prog1_3.c main file. I am almost certain the reason I am messing up is because I am using the Stack structure in the wrong way. The specific line I believe I am messing up on is

```
//prog1_3.c
STACK *myStack;
```

and then I go along and use myStack as a the variable in the push and pop parameters like for instance Pop(myStack) or Push(myStack,value). These exact lines yield be a segmentation fault core dumped. Any input on guiding me through on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What are the definitions/declarations for `Pop` and `push` ?

Comment: But you don't show relevant parts of `prog1_3.c`, nor the push/pop functions. That makes it difficult to help you.

Comment: Does `prog1_2.c` include you header?  Why not show that?  Does it include `<stdlib.h>`?  That could be important — show it.  Does `prog1_3.c` include the header?  Why not show that?  Which function crashes?  It probably isn't one of the ones you've shown.  Please provide an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: Sorry everyone, I am a stack overflow noob so I don't know what I should completely include and what not. Swordfish actually answered the correct solution of my problem but thank you all for helping out I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
STACK *myStack;
```

-->

```
STACK *myStack = MakeStack(42);
```